Dart flutter_inappwebview code shows white screen after loading
this the dart code which shows white screen instead of the content on running on google and edge but it gives no error in the editor and I tried this code in flutlab it shows black screen with error in run and I get sure that flutter_inappwebview in installed by pub add and outated

Rejecting promise with error: Error: Cannot set properties of
undefined (setting 'nativeCommunication')

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              InAppWebView(
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri("https://abdoohmaad.wordpress.com/")),
                initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
                    javaScriptEnabled: true,
                    useOnDownloadStart: true,
                    transparentBackground: true,
                ),
                onLoadStop: (controller, url){}
              ),
             const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`

I tried just webivew but it gives many errors

Update  I added this to index.html above the  

run pub clean and run pub get there may be error related to pubspec files

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
